# Is JOYBUTTON_5 incorrectly defined in mmsystem.h?

Tags: c++, windows, gamepad

I'm currently writing some C++ code to detect gamepad button presses. I'm using the following code to define an array of possible button presses:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

this->buttons[0] = JOY_BUTTON1;
this->buttons[1] = JOY_BUTTON2;
...
this->buttons[31] = JOY_BUTTON32;
```

And then using something like the following to detect which button was pressed:

```
joyGetPosEx(this->joyStickId, &info);

buttonPressed = false;

for(int i=0; i<32; i++){
  if((info.dwButtons & this->buttons[i]) == this->buttons[i]){
    buttonPressed = true;
    cout << "button number " << (i+1) << "was pressed!" << endl;
  }
}

if(buttonPressed === false){
  cout << "could not detect button press, dwButtons was set to: " << info.dwButtons << endl;
}
```

This works fine for gamepad buttons 1-4. However, buttons 5-32 do not work. For instance, when pressing button 5 on the gamepad, the program thinks `dwButtons` is set to 16. The `JOY_BUTTON5` as defined in `mmsystem.h` is 257. So it seems to me that JOY_BUTTON5 - 32 are defined incorrectly in mmsystem. Is that right, or am I missing something?

Comment: What sort of joystick are you using? Querying an xbox 360 style (ms made) controller with this function returns mostly useless info. For instance, the Left Trigger and Right Trigger 'buttons' both alter the value of `dwZPos`. Depressing LT increases the value, while presing RT decreases it. As such, both fully pressed returns the same value in dwZPos as is returned if _neither_ of them are pressed. (32768). Here's a sample for working with that particular controller, using XInput - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26949/Xbox-Controller-Input-in-C-with-XInput

Comment: Thanks for your comment - it's a custom made 'gamepad' that's based on this: http://www.u-hid.com/home/overview_board.php. I have tried it with another similar device and the dwButtons does not match the JOY_BUTTONx constants over 5 either.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. :) I should mention that as well as the trigger 'buttons', the normal buttons returned values in `dwButtons` of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and 128. If you're getting the same values, it's probably a case for trying the XInput sample. The stuff in mmsystem.h has been around since win2k - I dont remember if we had HID hardware back then, but I suspect that stuff came in for winxp. (pretty sure WinXp brought us directX, of which XInput is a part)

Comment: @enhzflep yeah I found the same thing: the actual `dwButtons` value seems to double each time. I think I'm still going to use `mmsystem` and `joyGetPosEx` since it already works (mostly) and just not use the `JOY_BUTTONx` constants. I'll hard code the `this->buttons` array to contain 1,2,4,8 etc. instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using MinGW. Yes, it's a bug in their header files. The Microsoft Win32 header files have different values (the right ones).

MinGW currently has:

```
#define JOY_BUTTON5 257
#define JOY_BUTTON6 513
#define JOY_BUTTON7 1025
#define JOY_BUTTON8 2049
```

It should be:

```
#define JOY_BUTTON5 16
#define JOY_BUTTON6 32
#define JOY_BUTTON7 64
#define JOY_BUTTON8 128
```